# array comparison in TCL ns2

Tags: tcl, ns2

I want a code/some hints of comparison of one array with another array.
If one element of array matches with an element in the other array, return  0 with puts statement, otherwise one with some puts statement.
I try to search on the Internet but can't find any useful stuff.

```
array set foodColor {
    Apple   red
    Banana  yellow
    Lemon   yellow
    Carrot  orange
}

array set citrusColor {
        Lemon   yellow
        Orange  orange
        Lime    green
}

# build up a list of non-citrus foods
foreach k [array names citrusColor] {
        if {![info exists foodColor($k)]} {  
              puts $k;
        }

}
```

In this code, output shows those value that does not match with values in other array. 
But I don't want character or string comparison in array ,I want full array comparison with the other array if match show output match else not match.

Comment: please add more details about your comparison. for example add a sample output.

Comment: As you loop through citrusColor, you need to set a flag indicating which foodColor items have been checked.  Then loop through foodColor, checking for items that do not have a flag.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `array set` is as follows,

**`array set arrayName list`**

> Sets the values of one or more elements in arrayName. list must have a
>   form like that returned by array get, consisting of an even number of
>   elements. Each odd-numbered element in list is treated as an element
>   name within arrayName, and the following element in list is used as a
>   new value for that array element. If the variable arrayName does not
>   already exist and list is empty, arrayName is created with an empty
>   array value.

You should get the following error

```
wrong # args: should be "array set arrayName list"
```

The code can be rewritten as,

```
array set food {
    Apple   red
    Banana  yellow
    Lemon   yellow
    Carrot  orange
}
array set citrus {
        Lemon   yellow
        Orange  orange
        Lime    green
}


foreach k [array names citrus] {
    if {[info exists food($k)]} {
        puts "The key '$k' is available in both arrays"
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
The key 'Lemon' is available in both arrays
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
if { [info exists citrusColor($key)] && 
     [info exists foodColor($key)] && 
     $citrusColor($key) eq $foodColor($key)
} {
    puts "Key $key is in both arrays with the same value"
    return 0
} else {
    puts "Key $key is either missing or has a different value"
    return 1
}
```